# How do I roll back all or part of a commit to svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rollback

How do I revert all or part of an SVN commit using TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to identify rather you want to revert back "all changes" of a revision, or just a single file.  TortoiseSVN has only the "1 or all" approach; meaning, you can revert back the entire check-in set, or single files: not partial checkins.

### Entire Changeset

So, if reverting back a specific revision (and you want all files in that changeset to be changed), you will want to Right-Click -> TortoiseSVN -> Show log.  Find the revision/changeset you want to rollback to, right-click on that revision "Revert to this Revision".

There's another option which might interest you, which is "Revert changes from this revision", which will do a Diff-merge between that revision and your current version, and merge just the differences.  I find this more appealing at times; so, I can keep all changes inbetween the changesets.

### Single file

The other option is to revert a single file back.  You would again do Right-Click -> TortoiseSVN -> Show log; but this time, you can select a single file.

TortoiseSVN does not let you select multiple files in a changeset to revert back to.  It's either all, or just 1.

### Changeset checkins

For all others reading, make sure "checkins" only involve the files related to that change.  This should be common practice these days; but, I still find developers "shotgunning" the checkins at the end of the day, bundling up all changes for the day into a single checkin.

I gleam at those devs with w squint.  -_^

Answer (score 6):

**If you want to revert previously made commit (revision):**

With explorer:

1. Right click on file/folder you want to revert,
2. TortoiseSVN->show log,
3. right click on unwanted revision,
4. "revert changes from this revision",
5. commit->OK.

**If you want to undo locally made changes (uncommited)**

With explorer: Right click on file(s), TortoiseSVN->Revert.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively to what Bartek said, you can checkout a particuler revision to a local working copy, and commit it back to the head.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can only "revert" in the sense that you check in a new revision, which no longer contains the changes you wanted to revert. That is described in the other answers.

You can *not* actually undo a checkin (as in "it never happened"), the old state will still be in the repository's history.

Really undoing/removing stuff is a longstanding feature request:

http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=516