# Reject SVN Commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

I'm using `SVN` repositories environment with `Eclipse 2020-06` and `SubClipse 4.3.0` plugin. I'm working on a project in a team and I would like to know if there's a way to reject the other people committs for some reasons.

For Example: 5 peoples work on the same project, one of them committ some classes and when I see them in the *Synchronize Workspace* perspective I would like to reject it if I want.

Is it possible?

Comment: So you want to essentially "un-commit" a change that has already been committed?  Or do you simply not want your local copy to include everything that has been committed?

Comment: Yes I would like to reverse a commit done by other team component (that maybe has write and commit shit.. it happens sometimes). But, googling (and searching) around, I think is it not possible.. thank you anyway

Comment: You commit a change that undoes the effects of the unwanted commit.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611879/how-do-i-roll-back-all-or-part-of-a-commit-to-svn.